# How to use id of an input element for a button click event in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular9

I have a template as

```
<input class="ng-hide"  id="{{f}}" multiple type="file" style="display:none;"
(change)="getFiles($event)" />
<button mat-raised-button type="button" class="mat-raised" color="primary"
onclick="document.getElementById('{{f}}').click()">{{f}}</button>
```

Here f is a string variable with dynamic value and want to pass the same `onclick` function but I am getting error as

```
error NG8002: Can't bind to 'onclick' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

4     onclick="document.getElementById('{{f}}').click()">{{f}}</button>
```

How to resolve this issue. I am using `Angular 9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `document.getElementById()` you could use Angular [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var). In addition to providing more functionalities, it is the Angulary way of doing things. Also in Angular you need to bind to the `(click)` event instead of the `onclick` event. Try the following

```html
<input #inputFile class="ng-hide" multiple type="file" style="display:none;"
(change)="getFiles($event)" />

<button mat-raised-button type="button" class="mat-raised" color="primary"
(click)="inputFile.click()">{{f}}</button>
```

Here `inputFile` is the template reference variable.